# onLowMemory caused in Android

Tags: android, garbage-collection, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

Am developing a live wallpaper application in android. I face problem of onLowMemory. My application runs quite normally for 5 or odd minutes in the device after that causing the low memory error and its quit and restart again. How to resolve this error.

Comment: Do you mean OutOfMemoryError? Your description is kind unclear. Obviously you are having memory leaks in your code. As you dont show the code we can't help you.

Comment: Romain Guy states in his GoogleIO presentation on ListView that the amount of memory given to Android processes cannot be known by an application developer; he additionally states that your best bet is to use as little memory as possible. Since you are getting problems when the device has low memory, you should probably use less memory.

Comment: Actually when my application running in the device i can track the heap memory of the application, that(heap-memory) is increasing rapidly. When i call the System.gc() function it wont collect the garbage memory.The heap size is repeatedly increase. How should i resolve this?
The actual message i got in the DDMS is I/ActivityManager(2488):onLowMemory no more Background process...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse MAT tool for analyze memory issues in your application.